# How to make a 'mat-select' readonly?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I am working on a angular 5 project. There are many `mat-select` elements which is supposed to be readonly like text boxes. I found out that there is a `disabled` feature which is:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Choose an option" [disabled]="disableSelect.value">
      <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option2" disabled>Option 2 (disabled)</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

which out put looks like:

[image]

It fades out the text and the lining below get changes, is it possible to make it readonly?

Comment: No, not in the most common way, since it's mimicking the native `select` selector in HTML. [That has no attribute either of readonly][1]. [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: then something that can just disable the dropdown.

Comment: Tried CSS for disabling pointers?

Comment: The solution with `panelClass` worked for me

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add CSS to both select block and mat-form-field block, these can be applied automatically to all the select elements:

```
<mat-form-field class="readonly-wrapper">
  <mat-select class="readonly-block" placeholder="Choose an option" [disabled]="disableSelect.value">
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2" disabled>Option 2 (disabled)</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**CSS code**:

```
.readonly-wrapper {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.readonly-wrapper .readonly-block {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: this does not prevent the element to get focused and select options with keyboard

Answer (score 19):

You can combine an editable select with a readonly textbox and ngIf between them:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose an option</mat-label>
    <input *ngIf="!editing" mat-input formControlName="mySelect" [readonly]="true">
    <mat-select *ngIf="editing" formControlName="mySelect">
      <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option2" disabled>Option 2 (disabled)</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Except your textbox would show "option1" and not "Option 1"

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the mat-select form field with a input box and bind input box data with mat-select data.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use `panelClass` to hide options dropdown in readonly mode:

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<mat-select [panelClass]="readonly ? 'hidden' : ''"></mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today is 2023-11-09. I'm using Angular v16, regular `<select>`. Neither  `[attr.readonly]`, nor  `[attr.disabled]`, nor  `[disabled]` work.

Solution is

- .css `.disabledsel {pointer-events: none;}`
- html `[ngClass]="{'disabledsel': condition}"`

Comment: and you get the value from this select, because i can't

Comment: It simply cancels the pointer event.